# How to sort the List<Size> in Android

Tags: android, arraylist

I have a `List<Size> list1` which is from `parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()`
I would like to sort it in ascending order `(width * height)`.
I have tried `Collection.sort`, but seems not work.
What is the best way to sort the list? Thanks.

Comment: size is custom object...

Comment: see here...http://www.vogella.com/blog/2009/08/04/collections-sort-java/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a custom [`Comparator`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Comparator.html).

> A `Comparator` is used to compare two objects to determine their ordering with respect to each other. On a given `Collection`, a `Comparator` can be used to obtain a sorted `Collection` which is *totally ordered*.

```
final Camera camera = ...;
final List<Camera.Size> sizes = camera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
Collections.sort(sizes, new Comparator<Camera.Size>() {

  public int compare(final Camera.Size a, final Camera.Size b) {
    return a.width * a.height - b.width * b.height;
  }
});
```

Comment: but if I want to sort it in descending order. how to do it?

Comment: @jjLin just swap the areas when subtracting i.e. `(b.width * b.height) - (a.width * a.height)`

Comment: write another comparator and return `return (b.width * b.height) - (a.width * a.height);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a `Comparable` interface to specify how an object is evaluated against to other and then use `Collections.sort()` method to sort in the desired order.

```
class Size implements Comparable<Size>{

    Integer width;
    Integer height;

    public Integer getArea(){
        return width*height;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Size o) {
        return getArea().compareTo(o.getArea());
    }
}
```